# Targeting previous li element of DOM not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get this code to work, but I cannot see what I messed up.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li id="youraccount" class="active">
   <a href="#">Your Account</a>
   <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked sub-nav nav-list" style="display: block;">
```

When the `ul` is clicked I want to check for the previous `li` containing the class active. If so, I want to leave this `ul` alone, else I want to `slide` it up (close it)

My JS looks like this (from the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)):

```
/* close any other menus that are visible */
$('#menu ul:visible').each(function() {   // THIS WORKS PERFECTLY

    /* except if the visible menu is currently active */
    if($(this).closest('li').not('.active')){   // THIS DOES NOT ERROR BUT IT IGNORES THE ACTIVE CLASS
        $(this).slideUp('normal');
    }

});
```

So close the sub-menu if its previous `li` does not have `class` of `.active`.

No errors but it closes all menus. What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$(this).closest('li').not('.active')` will always return a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) (whether it is empty or not), which means that the `if` condition is always true.

You could return a boolean using the [`.hasClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) or the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if (!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).slideUp();
}
```

Or you could check the length of the jQuery object in order to determine if any elements were selected:

```
if ($(this).closest('li:not(.active)').length) {
  $(this).slideUp();
}
```

Which is also the same as:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').not('.active').length) {
  $(this).slideUp();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Josh Crozier, awesome! I was far from figuring this without  your help!

Answer (score 2):

`.not()` is a function that filters elements; it does not return a boolean.

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead.

```
!$(this).closest('li').is('.active')
```